# How can I enable or disable bone constraint in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine

[image: This is what I have done to target a bone to Suzanne]Actually I want my bone to target an object when it comes near so I want the tracking constraint to be enabled when the object comes near. And I want to keep it disabled rest of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "run armature" actuator. you can even set it to enable/disable individual constraints like the one in your example!

[image]

heres a simple setup with a  cobra lashing out at a cube.

[image]

Comment: I tried it before but it didn't work for me. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: may you upload a .blend or a screenshot of your logic?

Comment: I have posted my image above. can you send me your blend file.

Comment: adding blend to post